# How to set keybinding to move (rearrange) tabs in Atom?

Tags: macos, atom-editor

I'm trying to setup keybinding for physically moving my current tab, either right or left of other tabs (rather than click and drag to rearrange them).

I know user defined keybindings are added to `~/.atom/keymap.cson`, I'm just having trouble determining the command as I don't see it present in the default keybindings.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I found that Atom has a native keybinding set for this under as:

> <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd>: `pane:move-item-left`
>
> <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd>: `pane:move-item-left`

Comment: Just to clarify: the command works using the command palette, but the keybindings must be changed because by default the are used to select text in the editor.
Alternatively, you can install [the command-toolbar package](https://atom.io/packages/command-toolbar) and add the commands to your toolbar.

Comment: On MacOS, I setup custom keymaps for these commands under 'cmd-alt-shift-left' and 'cmd-alt-shift-right' which is working well. I also have move tab between panes (e.g. 'window:move-active-item-to-pane-on-left') under the similar keymap 'cmd-ctrl-shift-left'.

Answer (score 1):

The native bindings weren't showing up in `Settings > Keybindings`. Here they are:

```
'atom-workspace atom-text-editor:not([mini])':
  'ctrl-alt-]': 'window:move-active-item-to-pane-on-right'
  'ctrl-alt-[': 'window:move-active-item-to-pane-on-left'
```

Comment: The question was asking about moving tabs in one pane, but I was looking for across panes. This was very helpful. How did you locate the name of these commands?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [Tab Move Key](https://atom.io/packages/tab-move-key) package. It is simple, you can use alt page up and alt + page down for moving tabs around.

Answer (score -1):

command + [ = to move the block left by 1 tab

command + ] = to move the block right by 1 tab